# Javascript Class constructor - instances, pointers, and private var references

Tags: javascript, class, scope

I have a class I reuse, *often*, to the tune of possibly tens of thousands of instances in a given session. It occurred to me that creating all these properties within the constructor may be replication, that is each function is unique in memory and not a pointer, so I created a little test setup:

```js
const testTree = function (){
    console.log(this, this.konnichiwa);
}
const testFjord = function (aloha){
    return function() {
        console.log(this, aloha, this.konnichiwa);
    }
}

class Clown extends Object{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        const aloha = "Hello!"; //<- Private party
        
        this.konnichiwa = "Also hello I think"; //<- Everyone's invited
        
        this.testWan = () => {
            console.log(this, aloha, this.konnichiwa);
        }
    
        this.testTree = testTree;
        this.testFjord = testFjord(aloha);
    }
    
    testToo = () => {
        console.log(this, this.konnichiwa);
    }

}

//export default Clown; //this is an export in my application, used lots

const test = new Clown();
const otherTest = new Clown();

console.log(test.testWan === otherTest.testWan);
console.log(test.testToo === otherTest.testToo);
console.log(test.testTree === otherTest.testTree);
console.log(test.testFjord === otherTest.testFjord);

test.testWan();
test.testToo();
test.testTree();
test.testFjord();
```

**Part 1**

As you can test above, `testWan`, `testToo`, and `testFjord` are all unique per instance, but `testTree` is not. **Is there any way to declare a "pointer"/"reusable function" but inside class constructor?**

The issue here with `testToo` and `testTree` is that they can't access private vars within the constructor like `testWan` can. `testFjord` is a factory and can be passed these, but then the returned function is unique and won't be able to interact well with vars passed into it.

It's very likely not possible - I think it's a catch 22 scope thing - but you may know better. The only recourse I can think of is to add a property to `this` for each thing I need to use in `testTree`, but that exposes things I may not want exposed outside of the class.

**Part 2**

This part only applies if this is a generally consistent behavior, and not something *completely* unique per-browser. Does the engine hold onto references to things like conditionals (which I suspect are sorta anonymous-function-like behind the scenes) once the constructor has run?

I have a fairly knarly conditional setup I'm not going to shove in the code here. This is entirely within the constructor right now. I suspect that, although not a function declaration itself, it is also not a pointer, but an entirely fresh instance per the 'new' in `new Clown`. It needs to manipulate some private vars and so per **Part 1** I haven't figured out a good way to extract this.

Example, there are references to private vars inside the constructor for exposed functions: `aloha` above is private but used by public `testWan` function, and so needs to be held after constructor has executed. Is the entire constructor held for the life of `test` & `otherTest` or is the constructor going to be dropped after use and just the reference to `aloha` held in memory?

Comment: TL;DR: yes, this is inefficient, you should be using the prototype instead. No, prototype methods have no access to "private" variables, since "private variables" aren't really a things in JS. Asterisk: do see *private properties*. Privacy is pretty overrated, what are you *really* protecting? Consider standard properties and prototype methods.

Comment: @deceze I will review prototypes again, perhaps it's better for what I'm doing. "private" being "properties I don't want other developers to jack around with in our SPA", I'm basically creating the 'framework' and they're not javascript types and will totally (unintentionally) break stuff given the chance. This just... keeps the craziness to a minimum.

Comment: At some point defensive programming stops making sense, don't overcomplicate your codebase if the real problem is communication and education of other developers, or simply not worrying about it.

Comment: @deceze usually agree. This particular case, it's a class (currently) that's used for all data handling across the application. It handles all communication and storage, and conversion to and from the API and forms useful to the app, in a strict pattern. Mostly, the raw values that should never be touched are kept as private vars, with getter/setters to interact with them. I don't want the other devs to "cheat" and try to manipulate those values outside the pattern set by this. Basically it's a convention-enforcement thing here. "Just use this, ignore the man behind the curtain"

Comment: *Usually* that's done with naming patterns like `_privateVar`, and you can wrap your getters and setters around that. If developers still go out of their way and write code against those clearly marked private vars, then you really do have a human resources problem. Typescript with explicit `private` markers and an enforced build pipeline could help even against that…